# How to get instance of my object inside a Timer

Tags: java, timer

I'm learning Java right now, I have timer inside one of my functions like so:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private void someFunction() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
               // here lies the problem
            }
        },
        1000);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is call another function `someOtherFunction(SomeClass c)` that takes as an argument an instance of `SomeClass`. Outside of the timer, I could simply say `someOtherFunction(this)`, but inside the timer that doesn't work since `this` is a `TimerTask`.

What can I do to get the instance of `SomeClass` inside my timer?

Comment: `SomeClass.this` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `SomeClass.this` to get the outer class instance inside of the inner class.